# Dynamic vector graphics in ViewBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I create dynamic vector graphics in xaml. I will discuss the simple situation based on the picture below.

I have sides (length and width) of the element.
They are bound with the parameter in ViewModel.
On the dimension line are the values of the current side length. Also it is bound with the value in ViewModel.

The text A1 and A2 is always the same.

How to arrange all elements in the ViewBox to:

- dimensional lines along with the length values always remained the same size?
- the text A1, A2 has always been the same size and in the same place relative to the side?

Moving these elements out of the ViewBox does not help because then they behave differently than the contents of the ViewBox.

There is a lot of information in this forum to move the item out of the ViewBox and put everything in Grid. This applies, but only for simple drawings, without parameterization of values. In this case, it's hard for me to use it to work properly.

[image: img]

Comment: Instead of a Viewbox, I would suggest to put everything in a Canvas, and use Paths for the drawings, where you could use arbitrary Geometries, and even transform them by assigning appropriate Transforms to the `Geometry.Transform` property.

Comment: I just kind of assumed the drawings are in a canvas which is in a viewbox. I think a bit more explanation of how this works would be useful. Do you literally mean you want something in a viewbox to remain the same distance from one side as the viewbox increases and decreases in size? What's the purpose of the viewbox in your view?